# Tree node context menu design, what would you expect?

Tags: user-interface, treeview, contextmenu, treenode

My team is designing a set of applications, some of them are using trees to display data. The levels of the trees are 2-4 at the moment, might grow later depending on our domain model.

Lets say that we have 3 levels:

```
Book  
  Page
    Word
```

My question is this: What would you, as a user, expect to see in a context menu on the nodes on the different levels?

Example Book context menu:

> New Page
>      New Book
>      Edit Book
>      Delete Book

Example Page context menu:

> New Word
>      Edit Page
>      Delete Page

Example Word context menu:

> Edit Word
>      Delete Word

(I don't care about separators for now)
The thought about this example setup is that you edit the node you clicked on.
Inserting a new Word edits the Page you clicked on.
Only exception is the root node, where you can actually create a new root node.

All input is welcome an appreciated.

**Edit:**
I'm thinking, is this the right setup of the CRUD operations, or would you expect to see a Add Page in the context menu for a Page node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing a few below which come to my mind -

```
Refresh
Move
Rename
```

There could be more based upon what operations can be done on the items as per the functionality in your application. Best thing is to ask the customer\business ambassadors and 
build only what is needed.

**Edit:**

IMO, Add Page should be available only on the Book element.